# Same KnownType Attribute For Multiple Abstract Classes

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, attributes

I'd like to know if I can add the same class as a knowntype to multiple abstract classes.

My problem at the moment is that I have two abstract classes in the same namespace:

Let's call this namespace "Thing"

I have two abstract classes in Thing, Fruit and Vegetable.

Both of these abstract classes are inherited by the two different classes in the same namespace, but have the same name. "Tomato"

So I have two declarations:

```
namespace Thing

[KnownType(typeof(Tomato))]
public abstract class Fruit {}

public sealed class Tomato: Fruit{}
```

as well as

```
namespace Thing

[KnownType(typeof(Tomato))]
public abstract class Vegetable {}

public sealed class Tomato: Vegetable{}
```

Type 'Thing.Tomato' cannot be added to list of known types since another type 'Thing.Tomato' with the same data contract name "{datacontractname: Tomato}" is already present.

I've refactored the two declarations of Tomato into it's own file and now one single declaration.  Now everything will serialize, but when I look at the custom attributes for both abstract classes only one of them will get the knowntype attribute.  That class will also be the only one that knows that it has a subclass of Tomato.

Edit: I was a bit too hasty with my refactor as I need Tomato to have multiple inheritance.  At the moment I've changed namespace Thing to Thing.Fruit and Thing.Vegetable, keeping the multiple declarations.  The duplication of code makes me dubious that this is a good solution though.

Comment: You cannot even have two classes called Tomato in the same namespace...

Comment: Right, I thought that was fishy, since I inherited the code.  Since then I've refactored tomato to a single declaration in the namespace.

Comment: Can you show your changed code? Because if you refactored Tomato to a single declaration, doesn't that mean you now only have a single Tomato class?

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake.  Let me take a look at this code and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Turns out they WERE in different namespaces, but they were SUPPOSED to be in the same one.  Regardless that duplication was bad, although I'm not sure the workaround was much better.  However, the workaround did keep functionality intact while allowing for serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using multiple interfaces (which would have been much better), I decided to chain inherit a couple of abstract classes instead.  I don't have a strong enough understanding of how we do our serialization (tons of surrogates everywhere with lots of legacy stuff) to implement multiple interface inheritance.  In my original example it would have been something like:

```
namespace Thing

[KnownType(typeof(Tomato))]
public abstract class Fruit : Vegetable { }

public sealed class Tomato : Fruit{}

namespace Thing

[KnownType(typeof(Tomato))]
public abstract class Vegetable {}

public sealed class Carrot : Vegetable{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritence is not supported by C#.
Tomato cannot inherit from both Fruit and Vegetable so KnownType attribute can only be used by the base class.

Comment: Since multiple inheritence isn't supported, is my only option to duplicate declarations in separate namespaces?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. If you really need a single Tomato class that can be used both as a Vegetable or a Fruit, then multiple Tomato classes will not do the work. What you need I think is to define IFruit and IVegetable interfaces and implement them both in the tomato class.